# matrix multiplication in python with wrong dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

how does this code work?

```
x=np.array([2,6])
a=np.array([[-1,0],[0,1]]);
print(x.shape)
print(a.shape)
x.dot(a)
a.dot(x)
```

now x is 2x1 matrix and a is 2x2 matrix
x * a 2x1 * 2x2 shouldn't that give error due to dimiension are not valid it should be like mxn * nxw = mxw?
although it doesn't give me error and solves it and return `array([-2,  6])`

Comment: x is not 2x1, x has shape 2. To have x be 2x1 it needs to look like this [[2], [6]]

Comment: You printed `x.shape`, and still try to tell us it is a 2x1 matrix?  Have you read the docs for `np.dot`?  and paid particular attention to how it handles arguments with different numbers of dimensions?